# Why Process CPU % Usage larger than Total CPU Time

Tags: performance, cpu, top

When I run the TOP command, a process shows 1208% cpu usage and the total CPU usr time is 81.7% with IRIX mode on. When I change to IRIX mode off, the process shows 99% cpu usage and the total user cpu time is 43%.

Any ideas what might be going on?

**Update**
Could the VM be misconfigured so CPU usage is not reported correctly?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have?

Comment: 4 on the vm, 16 on the host.

Answer (score 12):

**Irix** / **Solaris** Mode(`man 1 top`):

```
     <I> :Irix/Solaris_Mode_toggle
          When operating in  'Solaris  mode'  ('I'  toggled  Off),  a
          task's  cpu  usage  will  be divided by the total number of
          CPUs.  After issuing this command, you'll  be  informed  of
          the new state of this toggle.
```

...

```
      if 'Irix mode' is Off,  top  will  operate  in
      'Solaris  mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the
      total number of CPUs.  You toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes with the
      'I' interactive command
```

Let say `N` is the total number of CPUs. Then
In `Irix` mode, `%CPU` is the CPU usage out of `N * 100%`.
In `Solaris` mode,`%CPU` is the`%CPU in Irix mode` / `N`.

See: [`Comprehending 'top' CPU usage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032357/comprehending-top-cpu-usage)

---

**EDIT**:

> the total **user** cpu time is 43%

I think that you have ignored the **%system**(*Percentage of CPU utilization for executing at the system(kernel) level.* ) **time**.
Try other tools like `mpstat`,`iostat` and `sar` for analyzing CPU utilization.

Comment: Hi John, %system time was near 0. I'm trying to understand the discrepancy. Could it be a mis-configuration of the VM not reporting cpu usage correctly?