# The sum of % in the CPU column doesn't match the total CPU % row

Tags: process, monitoring, top, cpu-usage

I don't understand why the sum of % in the cpu column in `top` doesn't match the total CPU % row:

[image]

Text version with slightly different values:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ top
top - 23:20:21 up  5:18,  3 users,  load average: 10.28, 10.36, 10.20
Tasks: 299 total,  11 running, 288 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 41.7 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  99007376 total, 83451488 used, 15555892 free,    36212 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  5139148 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5914 ubuntu    20   0   25784   3396   1452 S   1.3  0.0   0:05.33 htop
 1473 root      20   0  373896   1444   1012 S   1.0  0.0   0:03.72 automount
  263 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   1:37.69 kworker/7:1
 6000 ubuntu    20   0   23812   1864   1176 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.41 top
    1 root      20   0   33500   2908   1496 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.87 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.36 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.48 kworker/u48:0
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:49.74 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.74 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.69 rcuos/1
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.87 rcuos/2
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.90 rcuos/3
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.58 rcuos/4
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.34 rcuos/5
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.79 rcuos/6
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.92 rcuos/7
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.77 rcuos/8
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.51 rcuos/9
```

What could explain this?

`htop` shows the same:

[image]

The computer has 24 cores. More exactly, it's a virtual machine on an OpenStack cluster.

`top` video:

[image]

Comment: does this helps ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15733/why-process-cpu-usage-larger-than-total-cpu-time?rq=1

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Thanks, this explains why  the sum of % CPU can be larger than the total % CPU. But how can it be lower shown in the screenshots and the question?

Comment: it says why sometimes usage shown is low or higher than actual usage in the first link

Comment: Please paste actual text next time, not screenshots (and certainly not a GIF!)

Comment: "What could explain this?" (the only question you are asking) can be easily answered: the source code of `top`.

Comment: @Wildcard added

Comment: @Anthon Thanks I'm looking for some higher-level answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be that `top` is reading the whole usage of the physical CPUs, not of the virtual CPUs.

It is also possible, that there are some processess running, that are hidden for the `ubuntu` user.

Also try running `ps aux`.

You can type the `1` number while running `top` to get detailed information about the CPUs usages.

Here is the notation from `man top` point 2b:

```
us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
sy, system  : time running kernel processes
ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
si : time spent servicing software interrupts
st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
```

[image: CPU full load]

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, i.e. the sum of % CPU can be larger than the total % CPU. But how can it be lower shown  in the screenshots and the question?

Comment: It seems that `top` is reading the load of the physical CPUs, not of the virtual. You can also press the `1` number while running `top` to get more details....

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt run `ps aux` to see if there are some running processes, that you can't see with `top`..

Comment: There are indeed instructions that read the physical CPUs, while others read the virtual. My fault too I never remember which is which. I could search vmstat or mpstat are the virtual ones.